# Change 127.0.0.1 to 0.0.0.0 for a AWS Service

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, networking, aws-xray

Installed AWS x-ray on a ec2 instance. Its listening on 127.0.0.1:port number. I want to make it listen to the open traffic(0.0.0.0)
Can we do that?

Comment: It's listening on the loopback for a reason.  What do you intend to accomplish by changing that?

Comment: I guess @Bharat is trying to use this EC2 instance as a standalone X-Ray daemon server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the `cfg.yaml` file (which should be alongside with the daemon) to add:

`Socket:
  UDPAddress: "0.0.0.0:3000"
  TCPAddress: "0.0.0.0:3000"`

or use command line option `-b "0.0.0.0:3000" -t "0.0.0.0:3000"` when start the daemon. Please note the TCP address is only valid on X-Ray daemon `3.x`. You can see how to configure the daemon at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-daemon-configuration.html.

You usually need to make it listen to public when you run your application and X-Ray daemon in multi-docker containers and what is your use case on an EC2 instance?